# Underline format problem

Tags: html, editor, format, tinymce, rte

According to the [documentation](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/custom_formats.php) i would like to overwrite predefined formats using this settings:

```
formats: {
        bold : {inline : 'b' },  
        italic : {inline : 'i' },
        underline: { inline: 'u' }
    },
```

I insert "this is a text" into the editor and press the underline-button.
This is the result (this gets saved to database too):

```
<p>thi<span style="text-decoration: underline;">s is a t</span>ext</p>
```

**Why do i get no u-tags, but the predefined span with underlined style?
How do i get my lovely u-tags here?**

**EDIT:**  **I do know that u-tags are deprecated**, but i need them for compatibility reasons!

**EDIT2: My solution thanks to the accepted answer:**

I was able to use some code from the legacyoutput plugin. I used the i[nline_styles setting](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3ainline_styles)

```
inline_styles: false,
```

additionally ia dded the following code into one of my plugins onInit

```
serializer = ed.serializer;

// Force parsing of the serializer rules
serializer._setup();

// Check that deprecated elements are allowed if not add them
tinymce.each('b,i,u'.split(','), function(name) {
  var rule = serializer.rules[name];

  if (!rule) serializer.addRules(name);
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The real answer here turned out to be:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin:legacyoutput
*(see comments)*

---

I don't know whether this is correct, I'm just reiterating what I [found here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=12291):

Firstly, you're warned that:

> `<u>` is deprecated.

Then:

> Disable inline_styles option.
>   Inline styles converts most attributes into CSS style attributes - so it will use span tags rather than `<u>`, `<strike>`, etc. So, disabling this option (which is now enabled by default) gives the behaviour you're looking for.

Alternatively:

> This will do it:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    formats : {
        underline : {inline : 'u', exact : true}
        }

...
```

Good luck!

Comment: i do need u-tags for compatibility reasons. Unfortunatly, underline : {inline : 'u', exact : true} does not work

Comment: @Thariama: The only other thing mentioned in that thread was this: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin:legacyoutput - however, that does more than just `<u>`. If none of this is useful, I will delete my answer.

Comment: +1 thx, this is usefull (works), but i still do not know if there are any other things the legacyoutput plugin does which might affect something else

Comment: @Thariama: If the other changes become a problem, it might be worth forking the plugin to only handle `<u>` tags. I imagine it would be relatively easy - just remove stuff to do with other tags from the plugin.

Comment: found that out too and decided to use the few lines necessary to produce the u-tags only

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for this, I also need the `<u>` tags for SSRS 2008 reports which do not support the new `<span style="text-decoration: underline;">` tag.

This combination worked for me:

```
inline_styles: false,
formats: {
    underline: { inline: 'u', exact : true }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works here?

http://jsfiddle.net/dFY6r/

Also `u` tags are deprecated, along with `b` and `i` that is why we use CSS now:

```
.className {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: I think he just wants the `<u>` tag because it's shorter (and he doesn't care [or know?] that it's deprecated).

Comment: @thirtydot - Well that is true, but doesn't hurt to educate right? I try and make sure all of my answers are standards compliant (unless its some ridiculous XHTML Strict caveat...

Comment: i do not want any span tags at all, i want a u-tag (this is crucial)