# Wordpress TinyMCE use U instead of style text docration underline

Tags: html, wordpress, tinymce, editor

does anybody know how to change functionality of button in wordpress content textarea of tinymce? There is a "u" button (underline) which makes text

```
<span style="text-decoration-line: underline;">text underlined</span>
```

what I need is change functionality of this button to put in content:

```
<u>text underlined</u>
```

I know that i need to change the tinymce init but where can i find it? What do i have to write there? I need this in my wordpress blog, so please help me :)

Comment: I answered a similar question not long ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561161/wordpress-change-functionality-of-tinymce-button-u-underline/32563429#32563429)

Comment: yeah but where can i find the init? Never saw the init

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own shortcode to accomplish this. Add the following to `functions.php` and you may use *[u]* and *[/u]* around whatever should get `<u>`-tags.

```
function underline_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<u>' . $content . '</u>';
}
add_shortcode( 'u', 'underline_shortcode' );
```

Another solution, add this to `wysiwyg.php` after `tinyMCE.init {...`

```
inline_styles: false,
formats: {
    underline: { inline: 'u', exact : true }
}
```

This should force the present button to serve you with the good old tags. Although this is not recommended since u-tags are deprecated. (Source: [Underline format problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219822/underline-format-problem?rq=1))

Comment: Thanks, i will try that but isnt there a simply way to change the tinymce editors underline button? Or to create a new button in the editor?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. For a detailed explanation, look here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72394/how-to-add-a-shortcode-button-to-the-tinymce-editor

Comment: I know that there is a easier way with the tinymce init but i dont know how to do it. By the way: your solution do not work :/